# Symfony 2 : Save json and display value

Tags: php, json, forms, symfony, entity

I'm actually developping a personal project with Symfony2.
And i want to to do something but i don't know how to do that.
I have an entity `Recette` and in this entity i have a property `ingredients`
This ingredients property is a `json_array` type.

```
<?php

namespace sf2\RecetteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Recette
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="sf2\RecetteBundle\Entity\RecetteRepository")
 */
class Recette
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ingredients", type="json_array")
     */
    private $ingredients;

   // ...
}

?>
```

In this `json_array` i just want to save a couple of information.
Ex :

```
["name":"potatoes","quantity":"5kg"]
```

Here you can find my Entity FormType :

```
class RecetteType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
    * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
    * @param array $options
    */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name','text',array('label' => "test","attr"=>array('class'=>'test')))
            ->add('completionTime')
            ->add('ingredients',
                'collection',
                array(
                    'type'=>'text',
                    'prototype'=>true,
                    'allow_add'=>true,
                    'allow_delete'=>true,
                    'options'=>array(
                    )
                )
            )
            ->add('preparation')
            ->add('recetteCategories')
            ->add('Ok','submit')
        ;
    }
}
```

In my form i can add with jquery with any problem add an ingredient, but my problem is that i can't save the quantity information. i don't know how to display in my form two field instead one for an ingredient.

Currently when i save an ingredient i have this data in database :

```
["Potatoes"]
```

How i can display in my form two fields for an ingredient and how to save it in this format ?

```
["name":"potatoes","quantity":"5kg"]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'd like just to note that those "json arrays" are actually objects or hashes, and they are typed with curly brakets, like `{"name":"potatoes"}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example from doc [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Firstly you must create a [Custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) named IngredientType:

**IngredientType**

```
namespace Acme\RecetteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class IngredientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('quantity')
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ingredient';
    }
}
```

**services.yml**

```
# src/Acme/RecetteBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    acme_demo.form.type.ingredient:
        class: Acme\RecetteBundle\Form\Type\IngredientType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: ingredient }
```

And change [The field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#type) in your collection to ingredient type.

**RecetteType**

```
         ->add('ingredients',
            'collection',
            array(
                'type'=>'ingredient',
                'prototype'=>true,
                'allow_add'=>true,
                'allow_delete'=>true,
                'options'=>array(
                )
            )
        )
```